# How to make two SKPhysicsBodies NOT to collide in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

**I have a player with:**

```
categoryBitMask = playerCategory
contactTestBitMask = enemyBulletCatgory
```

**This character shoots bullets with:**

```
categoryBitMask = bulletCatgory
contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
```

but when I shot the the bullet the bullet is a bit over my player and my player jumps a bit cause they interact, though they are not set up to do so.

**How do I make SKPhysicsBodies ignoer eachother?**

Comment: Set their collisionBitMask to zero. By default they're set to collide with everything.

Comment: I could do that, but then my player would fall through the floor. If I only set the bullets collisionBitMask to zero it still interacts even if the players collisionBitMask is not the bit mask of the bullet

Comment: You can set each node's collisionBitMask to collide or not collide with any other node. For example, you could set player.collisionBitMask = floorCategory | wallCategory | ballCategory. However, if the other node moves, you will need to set the collision bits for the other node accordingly to ensure that they collide correctly. For example, if the ball is a moving object, set ball.collisionBitMask = playerCategory.

Comment: for the player I got: physicsBody.collisionBitMask = floorCategory | blokkCategory, and for the bullet I got: p.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory , so they should not interact. They are both moving by the way :) Could I listen for the event and just cancel any interaction if they collide? though that would create some overhead.

Comment: You can detect contacts by overriding didBeginContact.

Comment: The problem was that i did my bitMasks wrong... I did: 0b0001, 0b00010, 0b00011 I changed ut too: 0b1, 0b10, 0b100 and it all worked out.. Thanks a million anyway :)

Comment: Try let playerCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0, let enemyCategory:UInt32 = 0x1<<1, etc.